# build failed ( dotnet ef --Startup-project ../ProgrammersBlog.Mvc migrations add InitialCreate command )

Tags: asp.net, .net, .net-core, database-migration, entity-framework-migrations

I'm developing  a project using ASP.NET Core 5.0  and .NET5. I'm trying to add an initialcreate to my data layer using migrations in the powersell but I always get the following error:

[error : build failed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pYwsA.png)

My ConnectionStrings settings located in appsettings.Development.json file in my Mvc layer.  I'm sending these settings to service layer using loadMyservices method(start-up class) in order to connect to the database. As my mvc layer has a reference  to service layer and service layer has a reference  to data layer so I used "--startup-project" before migrations to solve the problem of "   creating an object of type 'ProgrammerBlogContext'. For the different patterns supported at design time." I couldn't find what exactly is causing this error any one faced this problem before ?

[My connectionstrings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GVWfX.png)

[sending connectionstrings to service layer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7DIvA.png)

[receiving connectionstrings in loadMyServices method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d7lTZ.png)

[My ProgrammerBlogContext](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ynqPD.png)

I made sure that there is no package versions confliction.Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design package version 5 is installed in Data, Service and Mvc layer.

I want to be able to use migrations commands with a successful build and be able to see them under my data project folder.

Comment: Add Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design in you Data project, then in Visual Studio go to View->Other Windows->Package Manager Console.
There change you Default Project to your Data Project and then write this command:
Add-Migration InitialCreate

Comment: Great this worked for me thank you very much. what happens when I set the default project to Data project?   and why does the command work from package manger console but not windows PowerShell ?